# How to do a simple test in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have some code below that gives square numbers. I also wrote a simple test that prints `true` or `false`.

```
numbers = (1..20)
test=numbers.each do |number|
  puts number * number
end

puts test == [1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144,169,196,225,256,289,324,361,400]
```

I expect it to print `true`, but it puts `false`.

I was wondering if anyone could help to see why.

Comment: `numbers.each` returns the input, in this case the range `1..20`. You want `numbers.map` to accumulate the results of the block into a new array.

Comment: ive changed it to .map but it still says false. Anything else need changing? @ChrisHeald

Comment: `puts` returns `nil`, which you could test easily in the REPL (i.e., `irb`). The REPL is your friend: it allows you to instantly test assumptions if you're going to actively avoid tutorials or reading the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to get your answer :

```
numbers = (1..20)
test = numbers.map{|a| a*a}
puts test == [1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144,169,196,225,256,289,324,361,400]
```

You are using first **test** which contents `1..20`. So you have to modify your code.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `numbers.each do |number| .. end` returns the range (1..20) and that's the value that test will be assigned to after the loop through `numbers` is done. So even if you deleted the line `puts number* number`, test will still have the value (1..20). So using `map` would be the right choice to keep your values in an array. But you should first delete `puts`, because it shows the value on the screen but returns `nil`. So if you used `map` but didn't delete `puts` test will be assigned to an array of `nil`s.